# How can we convert Excel(.xlsx) file to HTML(.html) file in pentaho data integration dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to convert excel file or csv file to html file dynamically. If columns and rows are increasing then whenever I run transformation in the pdi, it should get me html file format data updated.

I have done this.
[I took csv input, modified java script value, text file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqE4A.png)
I don't know how to code in java script to accept csv file and convert it to html file using text output.
I'm newbie in pentaho data integration tool and also in java script. Is there any way to convert Excel `(.xlsx)` or `(.csv)` file to HTML `(.html)` file ?